# A script to upload files to remote hosts with dat file with remote hosts ip's

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script to upload files to a several remote hosts.
However, when I execute the script, only redas the first line on the dat file.

part of the script that indicate to use the dat file data

```
# gradually uploading files (shared-files) to remote hosts loaded from the list (in the .dat file):
cat "${0%.*}.dat" | while read line; do [ -z "$line" ] || uploadFilesToDevice "$line"; done
```

dat file

```
root:password@10.29.0.10
root:password@10.29.0.11
root:password@10.29.0.13
root:password@10.29.0.14
root:password@10.29.0.15
root:password@10.29.0.16
root:password@10.29.0.17
root:password@10.29.0.18
root:password@10.29.0.19
root:password@10.29.0.21
root:password@10.29.0.22
root:password@10.29.0.24
root:password@10.29.0.25
root:password@10.29.0.26
```

After execute the script, only upload files to the first ip on the dat file - 10.29.0.10

Comment: code shown looks like it should work; maybe add `set -vx` to see what is happening

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please specify where I should put ```set -vx``` on the script?

Comment: before any commands you want to trace; and turn off again with `set +vx`

Comment: ok, I add it right on top of the script... however, I can see on terminal all the debug and verbose, but I can't understand why dosen't pass to the other line of the dat file, instead of end.

Comment: Do you get any error message? What happens when you just display the content of the "lines" with `cat ... | while ...; do [ -z "$line" ] || printf '%s\n' "$line"; done` ?

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```bash
cat "${0%.*}.dat" | while read line; do [ -z "$line" ] || uploadFilesToDevice "$line"; done
```

for this

```
DATA=`cat "${0%.*}.dat"`; for line in $DATA; do [ -z "$line" ] || uploadFilesToDevice "$line"; done
```

and worked!!!

Comment: You're switching from a correct construct to a broken one...